# Implementation of mean and log_variance in variational autoencoder keras

Tags: keras, autoencoder

As the implementation in Keras for the VAE https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/, we have to pass a mean and log_variance to calculate the distribution in the latent space.

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
"""Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

def call(self, inputs):
    z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# flatten layer
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

I don't understand how two dense layers can represent the mean and log variance without doing any special calculation? Because from the code above is just simply create a dense layer and receive result from the previous flatten layer.

Comment: I find this, it gives me a little bit outline of it, I am still studying the AE stuff in recent days. Keep learning... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353220/why-in-variational-auto-encoder-gaussian-variational-family-we-model-log-sig

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: You are allowed to interpret numbers as you wish. Just be consistent with your interpretation.

There are multiple ways to interpret the output of a neural network layer: Let's think about a binary classification problem such as recognizing cats vs. dogs. Cats belong to output 0, dogs belong to output 1. Our decision boundary is at *0.5*. A model's output of *0.87* will be rounded up to *1* and therefore mean *dog*.

However, in a regression problem, you most likely will interpret an output of *0.87* very differently. Think about predicting the likelyhood of customer churn. Here, you will treat the numerical output of a softmax (range between 0 and 1) as-is. So your output means "The probability of losing the customer is *0.87*.

See, we have the same numeric value in the output, both created with a black box model, but interpret the numbers vastly differently. The same thinking applies to interpreting the values of the latent vector(s) in a VAE. We just **define** them to be mu and log_vars. Notably, this means that we must teat them accordingly in the calculation of the normal distributions that we draw samples from as well as the calculation of the ELBO loss. This consistency enables the network to actually learn Mus and the logarithms of variances.

You see what I mean in the line `return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon`. This line contains the reparametrization trick for a normal distribution. It requires adjusting the variance of the distribution by a randomly drawn factor `epsilon`. We defined the latent vector to mean `log_var`, so for this calculation to work as intended, we have to invert the logarithm to get the actual variances. This is done by `tf.exp(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

The dense output layers are trained to output mean and log variance for the input using the Kullback–Leibler divergence loss function.

In the Keras example VAE model it is calculated in the custom train_step using the output of the dense layers:

```
kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
```

Comment: nice, but my opinion is that you haven't answered the question the guy asked. Yet, I, too, want to know the answer, could you give more details?